# Extend class that implements Interface shadows name

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

Consider the following Typescript classes:

```
interface ITest {
  example(): string;
}

class A implements ITest {
  example() {
    return 'Test A';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  example() {
    return 'Test B';
  }
}
```

This translates to the following Javascript code (see http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground):

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype.example = function () {
        return 'Test A';
    };
    return A;
})();
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    B.prototype.example = function () {
        return 'Test B';
    };
    return B;
})(A);
```

The code runs correctly and gives the result

```
"Test A"
"Test B"
```

But checking this code with [JSLint](http://jshint.com/) gives the warning

> One warning 17
>
> 'B' is already defined.

JsLint seems to have problems with `__extends(B, _super)`. But of course this is necessary for extending the class. So how can I make sure that JSLint does not complain when using inheritance in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run lint on your generated code. Lint is to enforce style and best practices on source, so it should be run on the input to any code-generating tools. The output of those tools will rarely, if ever, be friendly enough to lint and it's not something you need to read or validate anyway. When working with compiled languages you run lint on the source rather than the binary and this is the JS equivalent.

You should use a tool like [TSLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) to check the Typescript before feeding it to the TS compiler. If you're using Gulp (or Grunt) there are TSLint plugins ([gulp-tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tslint) and [grunt-tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-tslint)).

Comment: Indeed, that makes sense. I am using webpack, so I have to find a TSLint-loader for webpack and use it right before the compilation step.

Comment: I use webpack from gulp and run various lint steps before kicking off webpack, so as not to waste time compiling bad code. If you're using only webpack, that may be trickier.

Comment: I already thought about using gulp in addition to my current webpack-only setup. I am currently developing AngularJS in TypeScript which also needs a decent test setup that might require gulp anyways. So far I tried to avoid adding another tool to the build chain but perhaps your answer and the combination of tools required is a good argument for adding gulp to my setup.

Comment: If you're not interested in spending much time with the tools, I would suggest gulp. Getting a basic project to run lint, test, and webpack is pretty simple. Gulpfiles don't need to be very long and you can delegate most of the work to your current webpack build.